# How to access object properties within an array

Tags: php

I have some code that generates an array with an object in it and I want to access the object values.

```
   $results = array();
    $std_arr = array();
    $data['examlist'] = $this->exam_model->get($exam);

    foreach ($student_array as $key => $value) {
        $std_arr[] = $value->student_id;
        $results[] = $this->student_model->get_single_student_result($value->student_id);
    }
```

and When i log the results i got

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
 (
     [0] => stdClass Object
     (
         [exam_schedule_id] => 14
         [get_marks] => 23.00
         [id] => 1
         [exam_id] => 1
         [teacher_subject_id] => 1
         [name] => GEO
         [teacher_id] => 16
         [subject_id] => 1
         [code] => Geography
     )
 )
 [1] => Array
  (
     [0] => stdClass Object
         (
             [exam_schedule_id] => 14
             [get_marks] => 0.00
             [id] => 1
             [exam_id] => 1
             [teacher_subject_id] => 1
             [name] => GEO
             [teacher_id] => 16
             [subject_id] => 1
             [code] => Geography
        )
```

How can I access these 'stdClass Object' property?

Comment: I think it should be `$result[0][0]->exam_schedule_id` since it's a multidimensional array. Does `get_single_student_result()` return an array with an object in it? Looking at the name, you would expect it to just return an object. Then you would also get all the objects in one list instead of nested lists as you're currently getting.

Comment: assuming your array result is stored in `$arr` try like this `foreach($arr as $key => $item){
 echo $item[0]['exam_schedule_id'];
}`

Comment: Thax for answers but when i try **foreach($arr as $key => $item){ echo $item[0]['exam_schedule_id']; }** it duplicate for both result due to **$item[0]** ,index and i have dynamic index's which changes based on number of items

Comment: " it duplicate for both result" ...that's because the value for exam_schedule_id is the same for both data items. If you were to echo get_marks they would be different. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6dca1d9282424b3ce1f64228504aff172639b416 . And anyway, if you don't want to output both the records, then what **do** you want? It isn't clear. You made quite a vague request "how do I access the object". Someone is showing you how to access it, and you are just complaining about it. So to get better help, you need to explain what output you are really trying to get.

Comment: "i have dynamic index's" ...not in the inner arrays you don't. It appears that the `get_single_student_result()` function always returns an array containing 1 item. That array gets attached to $results. So the single item within that array will always be at index 0. Your outer $results array does of course have a variable number of indexes. But that's taken care of by the foreach loop. It's not really clear what your concern is on that point. Again, it comes down to the fact that you need to explain exactly what output you are really asking for.